# Dart / Flutter using specific methods in a generic class passed as a parameter

Tags: flutter, class, dart, generics

I'm trying to use more generic methods in my code, and I came across something that I'm not sure how to solve. I'd like to pass one of a number of classes that have a specific methods associated with them.  How would I defined something like the '.toDifferentString()' method below in a generic class definition?

```
class TEST<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  const TEST({Key key, this.selectedData}) : super(key: key);
  final T selectedData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(selectedData.toString()),
        Text(selectedData.toDifferentString()) // Error 'method not defined for class <unknown>
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a way to define this method so that classes can be passed to it? (or verify that the method actually exists in the classed passed?)

Comment: let you classes implement some interface and pass it as <T extends MyInterface>

Comment: that did the trick. Thank you. I’ll post a fully coded answer below to help out the next guy.

Answer (score 1):

@Dude was correct.  Just in case, I'll put the code I used for the next guy in the form of a full flutter app. (This works directly in dartpad.dev, if you want to copy and paste it there)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

abstract class MyInterface {
  String toDifferentString();
}

class TestClass implements MyInterface {
  TestClass(this.test1);
  String test1;
  String test2 = "this is test2";
  
  
  String toDifferentString() {
    return "hello";
  }
  
  @override
  String toString(){
return "overridden toString()";
  }
  
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TestClass testClass = TestClass('this is test1');
    return Scaffold(
      body:Column(
        children:[
          Text(title),
          TEST(selectedData: testClass),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TEST<T extends MyInterface> extends StatelessWidget {
  const TEST({Key key, this.selectedData}) : super(key: key);
  final T selectedData;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Text(selectedData.toString()),
      Text(selectedData.toDifferentString())
    ]);
  }
}
```